# Why is it the html showing the ID not the text? using Django

Tags: python, django

I've just finished to create my table in my views.py, but when i apply it to html, im getting the ID not the text, please see the link ive posted below because I cant post picture here, im newbee here

```
if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
    try:
        m = EmployeeUser.objects.get(Username=request.POST['p_user'], Password=request.POST['p_pass'],
                                     My_Position=request.POST['position'])

        #print(request.POST['position'])
        if m.My_Position.id != request.POST['position']:
            request.session['member_id'] = m.id
            aa = request.POST['p_user']
            ss = EmployeeUser.objects.all().filter(Username=aa)

            teacher = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Employee_Users__id=m.id)

            student_subject = Subject.objects.filter(id__in=teacher.values_list('Subjects')).distinct().order_by('id')
            student_section = Section.objects.filter(id__in=teacher.values_list('Sections')).distinct().order_by('id')
            student_gradelevel = EducationLevel.objects.filter(
                id__in=teacher.values_list('Education_Levels')).distinct().order_by('id')

            cate = gradingCategories.objects.all()
            studentenrolledsubject = StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(
                Subject_Section_Teacher__in=teacher.values_list('id')).distinct().order_by('id')
            period = gradingPeriod.objects.filter(
                Grading_Periods_Setting__Education_Levels__in=student_gradelevel.values_list('id')).distinct().order_by(
            'id')

            students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).filter(
            grading_Period__in=period.values_list('id')).filter(
            Subjects__in=student_subject.values_list('id')).filter(Grading_Categories__in=cate.values_list('id')).filter(GradeLevel__in=student_gradelevel.values_list('id')).order_by(
            'Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Grading_Categories'
        ).values('Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Grading_Categories',
                 'Grade').distinct()

        Categories = list(cate.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
        table = []
        student_name = None
        table_row = None
        columns = len(Categories) + 1
        #
        # # table header
        table_header = ['Student Names']
        table_header.extend(Categories)

        table.append(table_header)

        for student in students:
            if not student['Students_Enrollment_Records'] == student_name:
                if not table_row is None:
                    table.append(table_row)
                table_row = [None for d in range(columns)]
                student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records']
                table_row[0] = student_name
            table_row[Categories.index(student['Grading_Categories']) + 1] = student['Grade']

        table.append(table_row)
```

This is the models.py

```
class studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade(models.Model):
     Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
null=True, blank=True)

     GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
null=True, blank=True)

     Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

     Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

     Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
null=True, blank=True)

     grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
null=True, blank=True)

    _dates = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

    Grade = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

     @property
       def dates(self):
       # you have Year-month-day dates from the form
       return [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in self._dates]

     @dates.setter
        def dates(self, values):
        # '|' as delimiter
        self._dates = '|'.join(values)
```

and the html

```
<table>
        <tr>
        {% for v in table.0 %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <th id="thupdate">{{v}}</th>
            {% else %}
                <th ><input type="text" name="updatedate" value="{{ v }}"></th>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <th  hidden></th>
        <th data-id='headerss' id='headerave'>Average</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody>
    {% for row in table|slice:"1:" %}
        <tr class="tr2update">
            <td>{{row.0}}</td>
             <td class="tdupdate" hidden><input type="text" hidden></td>
            {% for c in row|slice:"1:"  %}
            <td>
                <input type="text"  data-form-field="{{teacher.id}}" name="oldgrad" class="oldgrad"  value="{{teacher.Grade}}"/>
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td data-id='row' id="ans"><input type='number' class='averages' step="any" name="average" readonly/></td>
        </tr>
            {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
    </table>
```

when i try to printing out the **Categories = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Grading_Categories__in = cate.values_list('id')).order_by('Grading_Categories')** it says **[1, 2]** I don't know how to get the text , please help me guys

This is what i want result

[Correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsCQj.png)

[my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMIis.png)

my database in admin.py

[admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qim.png)

UPDATE

when i try the answer of mr Chris

```
table_header.extend(list(Categories.values_list('gradingcategories__name', flat=True)))
```

i got this error **'list' object has no attribute 'values_list'**

**UPDATE**

```
students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).filter(
                grading_Period__in=period.values_list('id')).filter(
                Subjects__in=student_subject.values_list('id')).filter(Grading_Categories__in=cate.values_list('id')).filter(GradeLevel__in=student_gradelevel.values_list('id')).order_by(
                'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users', 'Grading_Categories'
            ).values('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users', 'Grading_Categories',
                     'Grade').distinct()

            teacherStudents = StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(
                id__in=students.values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records'))
            Categories = list(cate.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))
            #print(Categories)
            table = []
            student_name = None
            table_row = None
            columns = len(Categories) + 1
            table_header = ['Student Names']

            table_header.extend(list(cate.values_list('CategoryName', flat=True)))

            table.append(table_header)

            for student in students:
                if not student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users'] == student_name:
                    if not table_row is None:
                        table.append(table_row)
                    table_row = [None for d in range(columns)]
                    #print("table_row", table_row)
                    student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users']
                    #print("student_name", student_name)
                    table_row[0] = student_name
                table_row[Categories.index(student['Grading_Categories']) + 1] = rate
                #print("table_row[Categories.index(student['Grading_Categories']) + 1]", table_row[Categories.index(student['Grading_Categories']) + 1])

            table.append(table_row)
```

additional models

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Old_Student = models.BooleanField( blank=True)
    New_Student = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    Date_Time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    strands = models.ForeignKey(strand, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please correct the indentation of your models.py so that users trying to help you can just copy the code to test.

Comment: What "text" are you expecting? Your model does not contain a string representation

Comment: I cant post pictures, please click the link

Comment: please see my update question

Comment: please help me sir,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you do something like `print(myobject)` you want a more meaningful output than  etc. So it is always a good idea to add an explicit string representation by add the method `__str__` to your model. So let us say your model `gradingCategories` has got a CharField called name it would be something like

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

In order to explicity define the field you want in you list which describes the table header you can use __ to tell django which field to use. So try something like this

```
table_header.extend(Categories.values_list('gradingcategories__name', flat=True))
```

under the assumption 'name' is the field you need.

In order to get the student name instead of the id:

Change this line in your code

```
students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).filter(
                grading_Period__in=period.values_list('id')).filter(
                Subjects__in=student_subject.values_list('id')).filter(Grading_Categories__in=cate.values_list('id')).filter(GradeLevel__in=student_gradelevel.values_list('id')).order_by(
                'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users', 'Grading_Categories'
            ).values('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users', 'Grading_Categories',
                     'Grade').distinct()
```

to something like

```
students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).filter(
                grading_Period__in=period.values_list('id')).filter(
                Subjects__in=student_subject.values_list('id')).filter(Grading_Categories__in=cate.values_list('id')).filter(GradeLevel__in=student_gradelevel.values_list('id')).order_by(
                'Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Grading_Categories'
            ).values('Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__name', 'Grading_Categories',
                     'Grade').distinct()
```

if 'name' is the field in `StudentProfile` containing the name you need.

and the use this field when creating the table rows

```
student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__name']
```

Comment: I get this error sir 'list' object has no attribute 'values_list'

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted here is the code you are using? ```Categories``` is a queryset according to your code and not a ```list```.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the ""Categories = list(cate.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))"" the Categories is a holder of list of ""cate.values_list""

Comment: anyway ive solve the problem table_header.extend(list(cate.values_list('CategoryName', flat=True)))

Comment: but the student name still the result is ID

Comment: Sorry, but the line of code ```Categories = list...``` is not in the code you posted

Comment: but the student name is still the result is ID not the student name

Comment: Sure it is the id because in the values of your long 'students' query you only have ids of your foreign keys. Try adding something like ```Student_Enrollment_Records__studentname``` (or whatever field contains the name) to the values of that query and using that value as a name when creating your rows.

Comment: I've change all the Students_Enrollment_Records to Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users but still i get the ID

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Please post you ```Students_Enrollment_Records``` model and I ammend my answer

Comment: student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__name', 'Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__lastname'] how to add lastname?

Comment: student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__name'] + ' ' + student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__lastname']

Comment: it loops so many, the distinct not work when i applied this student_name = student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__name'] + ' ' + student['Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__lastname']